# jquery datepicker on either current date or selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got a jquery datepicker and I want to implement it like if not selected today's date. if selected, selected date using single date picker.

```
var autodate=$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();

                var choosendate='';

                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({            
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                    onSelect:function(){                            
                        choosendate=$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
                        autodate=$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', choosendate);
                        //alert($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', choosendate));
                        //alert(autodate);
                    }
                });
```

what happen here is, onSelect function does not get called in my current code. how should i implement it to get if not selected, today's date. if selected, selected date.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

`<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />`

**js**

```
var date= new Date();
$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker();

$("#from").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy",date));
$("#to").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy",date));
```

[try this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/ak6af74p/)

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are asking here is for [defaultDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({            
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                defaultDate: Date.now();
            });
```